# NetBeans + MinGW + C - file not found

Tags: windows-7, netbeans, c, mingw

I have installed NetBeans 7.3 (twice this day), and installed MinGW (many times today).
My OS Win 7 64

I tried to install MinGW with MSYS, tried MinGW with MSYS and MinGW DT, MinGW without MSYS, tried to install MSYS separate, tried to install as privileged user, changed PATH and compiler settings, to move project to "C:\prj" directory, and tried to add libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll to my project folder, but failed to compile anything everytime.

My PATH and compiler options at the moment look like

[image]

[image]

But when I try to compile something, for example (C/C++ Application)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Or whatever, it may be an empty file, I still get error:

```
    "/c/Users/samsung/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2/"C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
/bin/sh: /c/Users/samsung/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2/C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe: No such file or directory
make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 127


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 758ms)
```

I would be appreciate any suggestion to improve this situation. Thanks!

Comment: Well obviously the path to **make** is completely messed up: `"/c/Users/samsung/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2/"C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe""`, but I'm not sure where to correct it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have just found the solution to this problem on the NetBeans forums here:

http://forums.netbeans.org/topic54884.html

All you need to do is:

1. Go to `C:\MinGW\bin` and make a copy of `mingw32-make.exe`. Then rename it to `make.exe`
2. Now go to `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin` and rename `make.exe` to `makeOLD.exe` (just in case)
3. Then move your new `make.exe` into `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin`.

You may have to restart NetBeans, but you should find you can now compile and build!

I would love to know how this suddenly became a problem.  If anyone finds out, please let us know.  I have seen a suggestion that updating from Java JDK1.7.0_17 to JDK1.7.0_21 breaks the C++ compilation, but how that could happen is beyond me.

Comment: In addition to the above answer by @Martin, remember to check whether the MinGW install updated the PATH variable. It did not happen in my case and I did it manually.

Answer (score 1):

changing name didn't work on Netbeans 8.xx you need to use [Msys](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys) or [Cigwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)